# Resizing terminal splits

Tags: osx, iterm

I'm trying to find a way to manipulate my terminal splits

In my `.vimrc` I have `set width=78` When I have vertical splits and change back and forth the active split is at least 78 chars. It squishes any inactive splits to allow the active split it's set width.

Right now I use iterm2. I am using iterm2's vertical split ability. Can someone suggest a way to to resize the active split to have a minimum amount of chars per line?

I often do my vim on the right and have a second shell split on the left. I will accept solutions that require splitting the shell some way other than with iterm2's split key combos.

The splits have a border between them that can be dragged to resize. I have found a way to save the screen arrangement but there isn't a way to restore it as far as I can tell. Restoring the screen arrangement opens a new instance of iterm2.

Thank you